# AWS S3 ls command returns the folder name too along with files in it

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line-interface

This might seem like a stupid question but I am not able to find a reason for this. When I am running command aws s3 ls on S3 URI, it gives the name of parent folder in output for some of the buckets and for some it will just list the files in the folder.

Example:

```
aws s3 ls s3://test-bucket/test_folder/ --recursive --human-readable --summarize
2022-06-28 20:04:36    0 Bytes test_folder/
2022-06-28 20:05:58    3.0 KiB test_folder/file.txt
```

and for another s3 URI it will just list the contents

```
aws s3 ls s3://sample_/sample_test/ --recursive --human-readable --summarize
2021-06-29 03:24:08    5.2 sample_test/file1.txt
2021-06-29 03:24:07    7.0 sample_test/file2.txt
2021-06-29 03:24:08    5.1 sample_test/file3.txt
```

I am not sure what is causing this behavior, is there any documentation which I am missing here

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is likely because someone used the S3 console to explicitly create a 'folder' named `test_folder` but they didn't do that for `sample_test`.  They simply uploaded 3 files to `sample_test`.

What you see as the folder `test_folder/` is simply an S3 object whose key is `test_folder/` and whose size is zero. It doesn't need to exist for you to be able to upload files to `test_folder/`. It's just a visual convenience in the S3 console.

There are typically no real folders in S3. They're virtual, and inferred from the presence of multiple objects with a common prefix ending in forward slash e.g. `dogs/bingo.png` and `dogs/elvis.jpg` implies the presence of a virtual folder named `dogs/`, but it doesn't really exist (typically).

Comment: Thanks for replying. So it means that if we create a folder explicitly then it will be listed in the ls response but if I directly upload a file giving folder structure and not creating a folder explicitly, it will not be listed in ls command ?

Comment: Correct, and you can quickly verify that.